# Regex for matching BBCode Images

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to verify if the textarea has one of the following matches:

```
[img]https://example.com/image.jpg[/img]
[img=https://example.com/image.jpg]
```

This is what I've been trying so far, but it doesn't work, sadly...

```
/\[img(?=|\])(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))(?\])(?\[\/img\])/gi
```

Thank you.

Comment: This will not MATCH anything: (?=|\]) It will only LOOK AHEAD which doesn't 'move the match cursor'.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this- `^\[img(?:\].+\[\/img\]|=.+\])$`

**Note**: If you want to verify the link string is a valid URL, replace both `.+` with a URL regex matcher, you may find one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

## Explanation

- `^\[img` - This part is common both strings, this will match the `[img` at the start of line
- `(?:\].+\[\/img\]|=.+\])$` - This will match 2 alternatives, depending on the very first character

  - First alternative (first character is `]`) - In this case `\].+\[\/img\]|` will be matched. This will match everything (`.+`) in between the opening and closing `[img]` tags before finally matching the closing tag itself.
  - Second alternative (first character is `=`) - In this case `=.+\]` will be matched. This grabs everything after `img=` and stops when `]` is reached.

  finally the regex matches the end of line.

Check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/BJo87o/1)